# R: How to append rows to each other based on common cell value?

Tags: r, dataframe, append, row

I have a dataset where each pair of rows have the same x and y coordinates. I am trying to combine them in R based on this set of common cells by appending the second row to the end of the first row. Here is what it looks like now:

| Type | Length | Width | x coord | y coord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pool | 17.1 | 89.5 | 36.66 | 123.44 |
| Riffle | 62.1 | 5.8 | 36.66 | 123.44 |
| Pool | 82.3 | 79.3 | 35.74 | 127.56 |
| Riffle | 35.0 | 8.2 | 35.74 | 127.56 |

And this is what I want it to look like:

| Type | Length | Width | x coord | y coord | Type2 | Length2 | Width2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pool | 17.1 | 89.5 | 36.66 | 123.44 | Riffle | 62.1 | 5.8 |
| Pool | 82.3 | 79.3 | 35.74 | 127.56 | Riffle | 35.0 | 8.2 |

I'm pretty inexperienced with r and I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried converting it from a long to a wide format using tidyverse and the pivot_wider function, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. Any help is appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that there is not a single issue with row pairs, a naive approach might be column-binding subsets of odd and even rows:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~Type, ~Length, ~Width, ~x.coord, ~y.coord,
    "Pool",    17.1,   89.5,    36.66,   123.44,
  "Riffle",    62.1,    5.8,    36.66,   123.44,
    "Pool",    82.3,   79.3,    35.74,   127.56,
  "Riffle",      35,    8.2,    35.74,   127.56
  )

cbind(df[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df)-1, by = 2 ), ],
      df[seq(from = 2, to = nrow(df), by = 2), 1:3] |> setNames(c("Type2", "Length2", "Width2"))) 
#>   Type Length Width x.coord y.coord  Type2 Length2 Width2
#> 1 Pool   17.1  89.5   36.66  123.44 Riffle    62.1    5.8
#> 2 Pool   82.3  79.3   35.74  127.56 Riffle    35.0    8.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately there are definitely some singular lines that don't have a matching pair :(

Answer (score 0):

This should take into account cases where there aren't always pairs by generating an id first and then a row counter inside those groups to pivot by:

```
df %>%
    mutate(id = cumsum(Type == "Pool" | (lag(Type) == Type & Type == "Riffle"))) %>%
    mutate(cntr = row_number(), .by=id) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols="id", names_from="cntr", values_from=c("Type","Length","Width"))

## A tibble: 2 × 8
#  x_coord y_coord Type_1 Type_2 Length_1 Length_2 Width_1 Width_2
#    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    36.7    123. Pool   Riffle     17.1     62.1    89.5     5.8
#2    35.7    128. Pool   Riffle     82.3     35      79.3     8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `cbind`.

```
> unname(split(dat, ~Type)) |> do.call(what='cbind') |> subset(select=-(9:10))
  Type Length Width x.coord y.coord Type.1 Length.1 Width.1
1 Pool   17.1  89.5   36.66  123.44 Riffle     62.1     5.8
3 Pool   82.3  79.3   35.74  127.56 Riffle     35.0     8.2
```